# How does the {...props} syntax pass its properties down to the subcomponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using React-Router, I learned you can pass route properties down to a component like so:

```
<Route path="/lyrics/track/:id" render={props => (
    <Component {...props} title={"gah"} content={"blabla"}  />
</Route>
```

And somehow this appends properties of the props variable here that's a `RouteComponentProps` to the `this.props` variable of `Component`, so now in `Component` I can do for instance:

```
<p>{this.props.title}</p>
<p>{this.props.content}</p>
<p>{this.props.match.params.id}</p>
```

I'm just confused about the `{...props}` syntax and how this works, as someone relatively new to Javascript. Does that work because both variables have the same name? What makes it so these properties get added unto that particular variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreading doesn't have anything to do with the variable name, per se.

In JSX, anything that you declare inside of the tag becomes a property of the `props` object of the component.

All that you're doing in this case is getting the props from the route and making them available to the component by using the `...` spread operator, which would work for any given object.

If you happened to have another object that looked like `foobar = { foo: true, bar: false }`, you'd also be able to spread that object into the component props.

```
<Component {...props} {...foobar} title={"gah"} content={"blabla"}  />
```

This would cause the properties `foo` and `bar` to be available inside the component props as well.

Answer (score 3):

The `...` is used to spread values in any variable.

when you pass `...props` to `Component` you will get all the properties from the `props` variable.

read more about [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I was just about to comment the documentation for ellipsis operator. +1

Comment: Thanks, I understand this has something to do with this operator, but that doesn't specifically answer the two questions I asked.

Comment: @Asik read carefully this answer and READ THE DOCS, this completly answers to your question